# '80s (or earlier) TV series where a hooded man with two daggers appears behind a line of soldiers (or guards)

Tags: story-identification, tv

I watched this TV series in my youth during the '80s, but the series could be from earlier.

I think that it was a dystopic present/future.

The only part that I remember is the end of the opening.

A line of soldiers (or guards) wearing a dark uniform and with their weapons (a type of rifles) in a two-Handed or “Ready” Carry position started going down a set of stairs towards the camera.

Behind the soldiers appeared a man with a grey or dark hooded tunic. He is wearing the hood and I think that you can see his face very well. He carries a dagger in each hand. Then he raised the daggers crossing them and forming the symbol of the series.

Be aware that I could be wrong in some details, but I am pretty sure to remember it if I watch the opening.

Other details:

- It was broadcasted in ETB1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETB_1) and dubbed in Basque.
- I think that it was in color.
- There was a resistence or something similar.
- I remember two characters (boy and girl) running and explosions. But I am not sure if that was in the Intro or during an episode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the 1987 TV series *[Knights of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_of_God)*

[image: Knights of God title card]

> Knights of God was a British science fiction children's television serial, produced by TVS and first broadcast on ITV in 1987. It was written by Richard Cooper, a writer who had previously worked in both children's and adult television drama. Set in the year 2020, it showed a Britain ruled by the Knights of God, a fascist and anti-Christian religious order that came to power during a brutal civil war twenty years previously. It starred George Winter as Gervase Owen Edwards, the Welsh son of a resistance leader (Gareth Thomas), and John Woodvine as the Prior Mordrin, leader of the eponymous cult. Patrick Troughton played Arthur, the apparent leader of the English resistance, and Julian Fellowes played Mordrin's ambitious and ruthless second-in-command, Brother Hugo.

Here is the first episode, which opens with the sequence you remember, starting at about 0:21.

Found with search terms of *1980s TV series crossed swords*.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: Yes, yes it is. :) 

Wow! I had been searching for this serie for years and you have answered it in less than a day.

Thank you, thank you. :)

Comment: @NKCampbell: Sorry. I tend to do my answers in phases. I was trying to get a good shot of the opening. :)

Comment: @NKCampbell: Yes, it is. I remembered it on watching the opening.
Thanks everybody. :)

Comment: @Spkit2000 - I'm glad you remembered it and found the answer! What I was saying though, was that prior to FuzzyBoots edit that added more information, there was no verifiable data (other than your memory) to validate whether the answer could be correct or not (and thus worthy of an up/down vote) - the edit was forthcoming and my upvote is duly logged :) - thanks and welcome!

Comment: @NKCampbell: I am surprised too as how well I remembered it after more than thirty years. ^^U

Comment: Wow! Something I ain't even thought about for thirty years..I loved it back in the day

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Funny thing. I was curious how it was possible that I didnt find anything and you found it so easily. So I put the same words in Google. And it didnt appear! Perhaps because I am in Spain and it was a British show?

Comment: @spkit2000: Truthfully, the same search terms don't work for me now, but my search history shows that as the term I used right before finding it. It's kind of bizarre, actually. Usually, results don't shift that fast.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: Strange...
Well, then I have been lucky that it worked before.